# Changing the return value of a method

Tags: java, methods

This code is asserting that a created class' method which returns a certain value returns the right number. I have to insert my own code where `[???]` is currently.

```
class A { int m() { return 1; } }
public class Exercise {
  public static void main(String [] arg) {
    A a = [???];
    assert a.m() == 2;
  }
}
```

How do I change the return value of the `m` method of the class A so it returns 2, not 1?

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you need something like this:

```
A a = new A() {
    @Override
    int m() {return 2;}
};
```

Comment: I can't change the new class line to 'final A a', so I didn't put 'final' in.  It worked, so thanks.